# How to convert a complex number into desired form?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

For example, if I have a complex number like:

$$\dfrac{a+i\cdot b}{c-i\cdot d}$$

suppose  $a, b, c, d\in \mathbb{R}$ and $c^2+d^2\ne 0$,

how can I use mathematica to convert it into the following form with no $i$'s in its denominator:

$$\dfrac{(ac-bd)+i\cdot(ad+bc)}{c^2+d^2}$$

Additionally, if I use many such $a_i+i\cdot b_i$ complex numbers in some expression, how can I convert the expression into the desired form with no $i$'s in its denominator?

e.g.

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{1+i b}-\dfrac{i}{c}+\dfrac{d}{1+i e}}{-\dfrac{i}{a \omega }+a-\dfrac{i}{\alpha
   }+\dfrac{t}{x+i s \omega }+\dfrac{w}{u+i v}+\dfrac{\beta }{y+i \gamma }-\dfrac{i}{\omega }}$$

The mathematica code:

```
(a/(1 + I b) + 1/(I c) + d/(1 + I e))/(1/(I \[Alpha]) + 1/( I \[Omega] ) + a + \[Beta]/(y + I \[Gamma]) + 1/(I \[Omega] a) +  t/(x + I \[Omega]  s) + w/(u + I v))
```

And, if we suppose variables $a, b, c,\cdots$ and so on in an expression, are real matrices not scalars, how to `Simplify` them and obtain desired simplest form result since the commutative law will not hold for multiplication and how we let Mathematica follow such rules?

Comment: `ComplexExpand[(a/(1 + I b) + 1/(I c) + d/(1 + I e))/(1/(I α) + 1/(I ω) + a + β/(y + I γ) + 1/(I ω a) + t/(x + I ω s) + w/(u + I v)), TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]` should work.

Comment: Thank you! this is what I need. Do you mind if I accept the current answer or will you create another?

Answer (score 3):

For the first part

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, d]
conv[expr_] := Module[{den = Denominator[expr], num = Numerator[expr]},
  ComplexExpand[num*Conjugate[den]]/(ComplexExpand[den*Conjugate[den]])
  ]
```

And now

```
 expr = (a + I b)/(c - I d);
 conv[expr]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> "if I use many such ai+i⋅biai+i⋅bi complex numbers in some expression,
>   how can I convert the expression into the desired form with no ii's in
>   its denominator?"

It will help to provide example of input that one can use.

> And, if we suppose variables a,b,c,⋯a,b,c,⋯ and so on in an
>   expression, are real matrices not scalars, how to Simplify them and
>   obtain desired simplest form result since the commutative law will not
>   hold for multiplication and how we let Mathematica follow such rules?

I can't follow. May be you should make the above separate question and provide more clear example of input and desired output.

Comment: thank you. I have updated it with an example.